# How can I make Two Different words with different colors, change to the same color in one div?

Tags: css

Can Anyone help me with this? 
I have a div, inside the div there is an image and two different text. 
The whole div is a link but I want to make the two word with different colors when I go over the div and both text change to white.

Comment: Post your current CSS and markup. We can't [read minds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/140505) here.

Comment: How can the two words be of different colors and both white. I don't get it...

Comment: It's not possible unless you wrap it an element, i.e. `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any `HTML` code so just an idea (using jquery)

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img src="http://gpsarakis.com/images/icon_jquery.png" />
    Hello World
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var myDiv=$('#myDiv');
    var txt=myDiv.text().split(' ');
    var theWord=txt[txt.length-1];
    myDiv.html(myDiv.html().replace(theWord, '<span class="red">'+theWord+'</span>'));

    myDiv.hover(function(e){
        $(this).css('color','white').find('span.red').toggleClass('white');
    },
    function(e){
        $(this).css('color','black').find('span.white').toggleClass('white');
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BZJDK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to use JS for that then You can do something like this:
for example Your HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src='...' alt=''/>
    <span class='first'>Your text</span>
    <span class='second'>Your second text</span>
</div>
```

and styles:

```
div:hover {
    color: white;
}

div:hover .first {
      background: red;
}
div:hover .second {
      background: yellow;
}
```

Advantage of that is that You can have multiple words in spans. @Sheikh proposed You something like that in comment to Your question.